# Is it possible to open another app from my app using Branch.io?

Tags: android, ios, branch.io

I am creating an app that needs to open a third-party app that I don't control. I would like to have a user follow a link in my app. If the app is installed, it will open that app. If it is not installed, it will go to the app store for that app. The link is not a deep link. It just needs to open the app for the user.

Is this possible in both iOS and Android using Branch.io if I don't control the third-party app? Does it require modification of the third-party app's source code?

Comment: If said app doesn’t support any form of deep links (either custom or universal), there is nothing you can do.

Comment: As @Losiowaty has mentioned, the third party app would have to be modified to handle the deeplink in the third party App. Once, the third party has Branch integrated and handles deeplinking, you can add the Branch links belonging to the third party app within your own App and they should work just fine.